# Does SVN support merging into sparse checkouts?

Tags: svn, merge, sparse-checkout

I'm trying to merge a branch into a sparse checkout (all the files I touched in the branch are included in the checkout) and I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot reintegrate into a working copy not entirely at infinite depth

Does this mean what I think it means? That you have to have a fully recursive checkout in order to merge into?

Comment: I'm starting a race to see what comes first, an answer from SO or a full checkout...

Comment: Just out of interest, what version of the svn client were you using for this?

Comment: @atikat I'm using TortoiseSVN (currently version 1.6.14 but it was different when I asked the question).

Comment: Merging simple additions of files in a sparse checkout works just fine with SVN client 1.6, this might be restricted to some operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just an update for anybody that stumbles across this (like I did)...

[SVN 1.7](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html) now supports this functionality.  I haven't tried to reintegrate yet but merging a range of revisions seems to work well.

[TortoiseSVN 1.7](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html#sparse) also has some nice features for working with sparse checkouts.

Answer (score 1):

Merging into a full checkout worked, this is anecdotal evidence that you cannot merge into a sparse checkout.

Comment: FML!! My client has a multi-gig SVN repo and uses svn 1.6

Comment: @Civilian this is dependant on the client's version not the server version. Just use a newer SVN client.